# Reactjs + Flux: why merge?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I was reading through the source of todoapp-flux example, and in TodoStore.js I saw this:

```
function update(id, updates) {
  // original
  // _todos[id] = merge(_todos[id], updates);

  // my version
    _todos[id].complete = updates.complete;
}
```

I was wondering why facebook choose to merge two object, instead of just change the value of one property? Is there any benefit doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update can be used to update properties other than complete.  For example on [line 161](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/examples/todomvc-flux/js/stores/TodoStore.js#L161) the text is updated.

```
update(action.id, {text: text});
```

This updates text, without changing complete.  With your version, the above wouldn't change text, and would set complete to undefined.